# Excel VBA with single search criteria, loop for all distinct values

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error message when I run the macro:

> Run-time error '6': Overflow

I have two worksheets; Search and Data. The 'Data' worksheet contains two columns, column A with numbers I want to search through and column B with an alphanumeric value I want to copy and paste into the 'Search' worksheet when a number match is found.  Because a number I am searching for can be listed an unknown number of times I want a macro to loop through to find all of the instances, copy the value to its immediate right and paste it into the 'Search' worksheet in cell D3 and going down a row for multiple instances of the number being found.

The number I am searching for is found in cell B3 on the 'Search' worksheet.

This is a sample of what the 'Data' worksheet looks like:

```
ID          ISS_ID
108143      136KQV4
108143      173HBK3
108143      136KQX0
109728      7805JM1
109706      7805JM1
102791      23252T4
105312      6477LZ6
```

Here is the code that I have now:

```
Sub Acct_Search()

    Dim searchResult As Range
    Dim x As Integer

    x = 3

    ' Search for "Activity" and store in Range
    Set searchResult =        Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A3500").Find(What:=Worksheets("Search").Range("B3"), _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False)

    ' Store the address of the first occurrence of this word
    firstAddress = searchResult.Address
    Do

        ' Set the value in the O column, using the row number and column number
        Worksheets("Search").Cells(x, 4) = searchResult.Offset(0, 1).Value

        ' Increase the counter to go to the next row
        x = x + 1

        ' Find the next occurrence of "Activity"
        Set searchResult = Cells.FindNext(searchResult)

        ' Check if a value was found and that it is not the first value found
    Loop While Not searchResult Is Nothing And firstAddress <> searchResult.Address

End Sub
```

When I Debug it points to the `x = x + 1` line. Right now it is able to copy and paste the first value without issue but it is after that point that the error comes into play.

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly for me with the sample data you provided. What is the exact error message? Do you have the ID that you're looking for in cell B3 on the Search worksheet?

Comment: The exact error is in a Microsoft Visual Basic window and states: "Run-time error '6': Overflow".  It then gives me the option to End, Debug or Help.  If I choose Debug it highlights the x = x + 1 line of code.  I experience this error when doing a search for any number in B3.  When I tried with 108143 it pasted the first value as expected but then the error will pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem changed because you are not resetting the origin point of the search with the `After:=...` parameter of the [Range.FindNext Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx). Yes, you are passing in *searchResult* but it was not accepting it as the After:= parameter.

When I ran your code, I was thrown into an infinite loop due to the FindNext always finding the same second instance. This explains the integer coughing at being incremented above 2¹⁵. When it was changed to a long, that gave something else time to choke.

After I changed one line to definitively include the named parameter, everything cleared up.

```
  Set searchResult = Cells.FindNext(After:=searchResult)
```

This was reproducible simply by adding/removing the parameter designation. It seems that the `Cells.FindNext(searchResult)` was finding Search!B3 and since that wasn't the *firstAddress*, it just kept looping on the same Search!B3. It wasn't until I forced `after:=searchResult` that the `.FindNext` adjusted itself. It's times like these I think fondly of my C/C++ days without this wallowing overhead.

I've gone through your code and added a `With ... End With` block that should discourage any questionable parentage.

```
Sub Acct_Search()

    Dim searchResult As Range, firstAddress As String
    Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet

    x = 3
    Set ws = Worksheets("Search")

    ' Search for "Activity" and store in Range
    With Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A3500")
        Set searchResult = .Find(What:=ws.Range("B3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                                 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ' Store the address of the first occurrence of this word
        firstAddress = searchResult.Address
        Do
            ' Set the value in the O column, using the row number and column number
            ws.Cells(x, 4) = searchResult.Offset(0, 1).Value

            ' Increase the counter to go to the next row
            x = x + 1

            ' Find the next occurrence of "Activity"
            Set searchResult = .FindNext(After:=searchResult)
            'Debug.Print searchResult.Address(0, 0, external:=True)

            ' Check if a value was found and that it is not the first value found
        Loop While Not searchResult Is Nothing And firstAddress <> searchResult.Address
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've left the `After:=` parameter designation in although it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Dim x As Integer
```

to

```
Dim x As Long
```

Comment: Different error when I made that change.  It now says "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: I should also add that the when I choose Debug with this change it is highlighting this line of code: Worksheets("Search").Cells(x, 4) = searchResult.Offset(0, 1).Value

Comment: You need to check `searchresult is nothing `. Make sure you've actually found another result.

Comment: From the data above there are multiple instances of 108143 yet the error persists.  From that I should be able to deduce that the searchresult should not be nothing.  It is still only returning the value next to the first instance when I need it to return the values of each instance.  Is that what you were pointing out or am I missing your point?

Comment: Not sure off the exact reason you're hitting an error right now. Hard to analyze on a phone screen. However, you will want to check for not found because you'll eventually hit it